# Ripple XRP in circulation

Tags: ripple

From the 100 billion of total XRP, 20 billion went to the founders and 30 billion to OpenCoin to fund development. The 50 billion remaining are supposed to be given away to promote Ripple.

Is there any source of information tracking how many XRP have been distributed to the public?

Have any of the funds for development been sold?

Comment: May I ask where you got those numbers?

Comment: @fnieto-FernandoNieto please don't use a url shortener for links to SE on SE. Your link in full: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8519/how-long-will-it-take-for-opencoin-to-distribute-the-50-billion-xrps?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

this is pretty good article calculating how many XRPs are floating on the market

http://www.thebitcointrader.com/2013/05/ripple-is-now-tsunami.html

Comment: The article estimates that 500 million XRP are in circulation.

Answer (score 0):

This list is already a 2-3 weeks old but gives you an idea...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ap6WwaNTa-L3dHFhMWtEM251akdrLXo0TmVYa0RmS3c#gid=0

It lists the Ripple accounts and their XRP holdings...